# Need to change image size using CSS in Wordpress Bakery

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wpbakery

I want to change the size of this specific image, but the problem here is that all these CSS classes are also mentioned in some other tags,  whenever I do changes, it applies everywhere because of same classes.
How can I resolve this issue?

I am also unable to add another CSS class to any tag. That's why I change in pre-added classes.
The only different attribute here is a `data-loop` in first `div` tag and `alt` text in `image` tag, any CSS changes possible through these? If so, how?

P.S
If anyone knows how to access the HTML file of Wordpress page it would much appreciated.

#wordpress #WP-Bakery
Screenshot added
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsSge.png)

Comment: Maybe you need an id and not a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS lets you select on attributes so either, or both, of the attributes you mention could be used to help target the correct img.

See for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

> The CSS attribute selector matches elements based on the presence or
> value of a given attribute.

Comment: Thankew soo much <3 Solved